# Can someone help me understand Java Constructors and Methods?

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor

Sorry if this question doesn't belong here I just thought this would be the best place to ask. I'm currently taking school notes on Java classes and I'm very confused on a few things. Ok so

I need help with my Constructors and Methods section. I am given this code:

```
class Student
{
private int id, age;
public double gradeAverage

public Student()
{
 id = 10000;
 age = 18;
 gradeAverage = 2.0;
}
public void printData()
{
System.out.println("id: " + id);
System.out.println("age: " + age);
System.out.println("grade average: " + gradeAverage);
return;
}

public class Check
{ 
public static void main(String args[])
{
Student stu = new Student();
System.out.println(stu.gradeAverage);
stu.printData();
}
}
```

So ok I got a few questions.

What does the method printData do?

What does return; do?

Is 'stu' just the identifier for the new student?

I understand that other classes cannot use private variables, but my notes say "Any other class that uses the Student class does not have direct access to private instance variables id and age. So, a writer of the Student class can change the names of the private variables, for example, change id to studentID. This change does not affect the code in the other classes that reuse the Student class." How would you write that if you wanted to print out the age or id for a different student? The way they explain this makes no sense to me.

(ok I tried to stay focused on one thing and only ask a few short questions. sorry if this is still too much. im still learning)

Comment: *"I'll add more questions as they come to me."* - This question already contains too many questions as it is, and is far too broad to be answered.  You're essentially asking us to teach you Java.  The best thing you could do at this time is to continue with your Java studies and practice.  Tutorials, examples, books, courses, various educational materials, working with a peer/colleague, etc.  This community cannot provide personal tutoring services for you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: I see from your profile you are in the 10th grade and learning on your own.  That's fine; normally I would say to get help from your instructor and fellow students but that isn't an option.  What I think you should do is ask fewer questions for each question here on SO.  That'll help you get answers.  Then just ask another question when you need more help, it's better to focus so people can answer better.

Comment: oh ok thank you :) @markspace

Comment: What does printData() do? It prints id, age, and gradeAverage. Please take a basic java tutorial. This should have been explained in the first two chapters.

Answer (score 2):

> So, the accessor method here is col.getRed/Blue/Green correct?

Yes.

> Are accessor methods different for every class or are they similar somehow?

They normally all start with "get" but aside from that they will be different.  Accessor methods are a very broad class of method.  They return a value representing a property of the class.  That's it.  I think you're over thinking this.  Accessor methods "access" a property by returning a value.  That's it.

> If they're all different how do you make your own methods?

You just write code that makes it do what you want.